# AWS rds postgres session count keeps increasing and server becomes unresponsive

Tags: amazon-rds, nestjs, typeorm

Platform Used:

1. NestJs 7.1.2
2. Postgres

After a certain duration my aws rds session count keeps increasing and the server becomes unresponsive. I need to restart the server again to make it working.

My database connection code in main.ts:

```
import * as session from 'express-session';
app.use(
  session({
    store: new (require('connect-pg-simple')(session))({
      conString:
        'pg://' +
        process.env.TYPEORM_USERNAME +
        ':' +
        process.env.TYPEORM_PASSWORD +
        '@' +
        process.env.TYPEORM_HOST +
        '/' +
        process.env.TYPEORM_DATABASE,
    }),
    secret: process.env.COOKIE_SECRET,
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    cookie: { maxAge: 30 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 }, // 30 days
  }),
);
```

app.module.ts code:

```
TypeOrmModule.forRootAsync({
  useFactory: (config: ConfigService) => config.get('database'),
  inject: [ConfigService],
})
```

where my database config is as follows:

```
import * as path from 'path';
export default {
  type: process.env.TYPEORM_CONNECTION,
  host: process.env.TYPEORM_HOST,
  port: +process.env.TYPEORM_PORT,
  username: process.env.TYPEORM_USERNAME,
  password: process.env.TYPEORM_PASSWORD,
  database: process.env.TYPEORM_DATABASE,
  synchronize: true,
  dropSchema: false,
  logging: false,
  retryAttempts: 5,
  keepConnectionAlive: true,
  entities: [path.join(__dirname, '../') + '**/!(*.d).entity{.ts,.js}'],
  migrations: ['migrations/**/*.ts'],
  subscribers: ['subscriber/**/*.ts', 'dist/subscriber/**/.js'],
  cli: {
    entitiesDir: 'src',
    migrationsDir: 'migrations',
    subscribersDir: 'subscriber',
  },
};
```

Kindly assist...have struggled a lot on this!!

Comment: Why are you manually opening up connections to Postgres inside this middleware instead of just letting TypeORM manage connections for you?

Comment: @JesseCarter can you brief about this, few code snippets if you could share would be of great use!!

Answer (score 0):

Use the `pgPromise` connection param instead of the `conString` param. Also modify apolloServer+express-session configuration settings.

```
async function main() {
  const connection = await createConnection(ormconfig as ConnectionOptions);
  
  const schema = await buildSchema({ resolvers: [DysfunctionalThoughtResolver,UserResolver] });
  const server = new ApolloServer({ 
    schema,
    context: async ({ req, res }) => ({ req, res }),
    playground: {
      settings: {
        "request.credentials": "same-origin",
      }
    }
  });
  var app=express();

  var pgSession = require('connect-pg-simple')(session);
  app.use(session({
    name: process.env.COOKIE_NAME,
    saveUninitialized:false,
    secret:process.env.COOKIE_SECRET?.split(','),
    cookie: {
      store: new pgSession({
        pgPromise : connection
      }),
      httpOnly: true,
      secure: process.env.NODE_ENV=="prod",
      sameSite: true,
      maxAge: 600000 // Time is in miliseconds
    },
    resave: false
  }))

  await app.listen({port:4000});
  server.applyMiddleware({ app });
  console.log("Server has started!");
}

main();
```

Dont forget to add the session table required in connect-pg-simple:

https://github.com/voxpelli/node-connect-pg-simple/blob/HEAD/table.sql

```
CREATE TABLE "session" (
  "sid" varchar NOT NULL COLLATE "default",
    "sess" json NOT NULL,
    "expire" timestamp(6) NOT NULL
)
WITH (OIDS=FALSE);

ALTER TABLE "session" ADD CONSTRAINT "session_pkey" PRIMARY KEY ("sid") NOT DEFERRABLE INITIALLY IMMEDIATE;

CREATE INDEX "IDX_session_expire" ON "session" ("expire");
```

TypeORM translation(put in a `session.ts` file in your models/entities folder).

```
@Entity()
export class session {
    @PrimaryColumn({
        type: "varchar",
        nullable: false,
        //collation:"" //needed?
    })
    sid:string;

    @Column({
        type: "json",
        nullable: false
    })
    sess:any;

    @Index("IDX_session_expire")
    @Column({
        type: "timestamp",
        precision: 6,
        nullable: false
    })
    expire:Date;
}
```

Then access it in your resolvers

```
  @Mutation(() => String)
  async login(@Args() { email, password }: UserLoginArgs, @Ctx() ctx: any) {
    let response = "";
    let sess = ctx.req.session;
    if (sess.userId) { response = "already logged in"; }
    else {
      let user = await User.findOne({ where: { email: email } });
      if (user) {
        let passwordsMatch = await bcrypt.compare(password, user?.password);
        if (passwordsMatch) {
          sess.userId = user.id;
          sess.save();
          response = "login successful";
        } else {
          response = "Password doesn't match"
        }
      } else {
        response = "User not found";
      }
    }
    return response;
  }

  @Mutation(() => String)
  async logout(@Ctx() ctx: any) {
    let sess = ctx.req.session;
    if (!sess.userId) { return "already logged out"; }
    else{
      sess.destroy();
      return "logged out";
    }
  }
```